# Nginx and Laravel: How to restrict "location" block to from "/" to "/api"?

Tags: laravel, nginx, nginx-location

I have a Laravel application that I would like to use only for its `/api` routes. When `/`, `/login`, `/profile`, etc are accessed, I would like nginx to serve the index file located in the base root, `/var/www/html/index.html`.

Here's my current `default.conf`. The `/api` routes work, but it also serves `/` from the backend, which I don't want.
If I simply change `location /` to `location /api`, then the `/api` routes become inaccessible, and trying to access them returns the index file located in the base root, `/var/www/html/index.html`. This is the opposite of what I am trying to achieve. Haha.

How can I keep the `/api` routes accessible, while also preventing `/` from being served by the backend?

```
server {

    listen  80;
    root /var/www/html;
    server_name _;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    # API routes should be handled by the backend (Laravel).
    ##### I want to change the following line from "/" to "/api".
    location / {
        root /var/www/backend/public;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your configuration, that should already be happening.

the directive:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
```

Will attempt first to locate the static file, and if the static file exists and is not a php file, it will be served by nginx directly.  Only if it is a php file will it be served with the php backend.

If you want to prevent `.php` files from being executed at all, you can modify to separate the `/` location from the `/api` location:

```
location ~ ^/api/.*\.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished this, but somewhat inelegantly.
I have 2 location blocks:

- `location ~ "^(?!/api).*$"` matches all routes *except* those that begin with `/api`.
- `location /` matches all other routes. The reason that it does not match *all* routes is simply that nginx matches location blocks with regular expressions first.

Strangely, using a regular expression for the second block to match all routes that *do* begin with `/api` did not work. I still don't understand why.

```
server {
  listen  80;
  root /var/www/html;
  server_name _;
  index index.php index.html index.htm;

  # All non-API routes should be handled by the frontend.
  # Use a regular expression to identify all requests
  # that do NOT begin with "/api".
  location ~ "^(?!/api).*$" {
    root /var/www/frontend/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
  }

  # API routes should be handled by the backend (Laravel).
  # (Since regex-based location blocks are matched first,
  # this will be a fallback to the above location block).
  location / {
    root /var/www/backend/public;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
      fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm.sock;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      fastcgi_index index.php;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }

  }

}
```